# ContextMenu in Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

How to create several MenuItems and add it to ContextMenu in windows phone 7 with C#?

I wrote this sample:

```
MenuItem q = new MenuItem();
q.Header = "something";
ContextMenu cM = new ContextMenu(q);
```

and in MSDN there's something about it, but it doesn't compile, because of construct of ContextMenu.

Comment: why don't you use xaml to add context menu? http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-ContextMenu-in-depth--Part1-key-concepts-and-API

Comment: besause elements of menu changes dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add menu items as follows:

```
ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();

cm.Items.Add( new MenuItem() {
  Header = "Item 1",
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ContextMenu` isn't part of Wp7 natively.  You need to look at the Silverlight Toolkit for WP7.

http://silverlight.codeplex.com/

Comment: Sorry... The original question didn't indicate that.